# Blazor RenderTreeBuilder builder Resize

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

im trying to bind the "resize" eventlistener to my component.
I dont know why but it isnt working for me.

`public event Action SizeChangedAction;`

`builder.AddAttribute(5, "resize", SizeChangedAction);`

OnMouseUp OnClick everything working fine.

`builder.AddAttribute(GetSequenceIndex(), "onmouseup", EventCallback.Factory.Create(component, component.OnMouseUp.InvokeAsync));`

Does someone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

The "resize" event isn't a [supported bindable event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in Blazor, it's a JavaScript event.

There have been some attempts to write size event handling code, see
https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazorSize as one example.